# Docker Cypress could not verify that this server is running

Tags: docker, cypress

I'm updating Cypress (v4 to v12.8.1) and the Dockerfile (10 to 18.14.1) and I'm having some problems that I'm not able to solve. I tried different solutions I found in SO and Google but it didn't work...

This is the error I get

```
Cypress could not verify that this server is running

We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your baseUrl.

Cypress automatically waits until your server is accessible before running tests.
```

I'm running the same commands I was using before upgrading (it was working). The command is this one:

```
docker run --rm --ipc=host \
-e CYPRESS_baseUrl=https://<IP-REMOTE-SERVER> \
-v ./test/browser/cypress:/app/cypress \
-v ./test/browser/mocha:/app/mocha \
--entrypoint npm <name>:<version> run
```

The Dockerfile:

```
# This is the unique line that has changed
FROM cypress/base:18.14.1

WORKDIR /app
ADD package.json .
ADD package-lock.json .

RUN npm install
RUN npx cypress verify

ADD cypress.config.js /app
```

I tried to set `-e NO_PROXY=<url>` (It was mention as a possible solution in one of the questions asked here in SO) but it didn't work... I don't know what could changed from one image to another but it's out of my knowledge...

Comment: What error is being thrown?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @agoff, I've updated it with the error that Cypress throws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the parameter/option `--net=host` fixed the problem and Docker is able to resolve my server.